# Is There Any Image Editing SDK Currently Available for Android

Tags: android, graphics, sdk, photos, image-editing

I have been looking for an image editing SDK for Android, something that includes an option for custom stickers. A good example would be the [Adobe Creative SDK](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/index.html)  (previously the [Aviary SDK](https://developers.aviary.com/)), though the current build only supports customizing which features to include, with no option to add your own stickers. Another good example would be the [Fotor SDK](http://developers.fotor.com/), which did support adding your own stickers, but it is now under development, with no way of accessing the previous version (that I know of).

There are a few more editing SDKs available, including the [PhotoEditor SDK by img.ly](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/) and [CLImageEditor](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor), but only for iOS. If anyone knows of an Android editing SDK with a sticker feature, or if someone could point me toward some decent resources on the subject (which I have not been able to find) so I can create my own, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I need the same thing. Have you found a solution? I tried Aviary, but it's not customizable unfortunately.

Comment: @Alvin No, I never did. I had to implement my own crude photo editing code. Most of my code is in one of my [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896471/android-surfaceview-flickering). It is not without issues though, I did not have much time to work on it before moving on to another project. The biggest issue is handling memory constraints, in the end I put a cap on the amount of stickers a user could have at one time.

Comment: I found the Adobe Creative SDK has become more stringent and useless esp. they keep rejecting your app for the final approval. They claim that the SDK is free for all but at the time of approval it feels like a robot is rejecting your app by asking more and more screenshots, I did not know that I need to make an app with 100 different screens :) . There is not clear way to reach out to the guys/robots there besides contact us form. It s dejecting one and guys do due diligence before embracing the SDK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Img.ly PhotoEditor SDK](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com) is now also available for Android. You can also easily add your own assets like stickers and fonts.

You can get a reference to the stickers array like so:

```
ArrayList<ImageStickerConfig> stickers = PhotoEditorSdkConfig.getStickerConfig();
```

For the complete example consult the [docs](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/android/customization#adding-or-removing-stickers)

Comment: Img.ly PhotoEditor SDK is not free. This needs to purchase license right?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani That is true, though the license is free as long as the app does not contain any form of monetization (documented in the [FAQ](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/pricing) as well as the [development guides](http://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/android/v3_1/introduction/overview)); which is my use-case.