# Android: SurfaceView Flickering

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am having an issue with drawing to a `SurfaceView`, when the bitmap images on the `SurfaceView` are moved, they flicker (or tear). I did not have this problem in previous iterations of my code. But now that I finally got the bitmaps to scale properly by using a separate `Canvas` for each bitmap, this problem started occurring. These are the important parts of my custom `SurfaceView` class:

```
public class DrawingSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public DrawingSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mHost = (EditorActivity) mContext;
        Log.d("DrawingSurface", "SURFACE CREATED");
        mDrawingThread = new DrawingThread(this, REFRESH_RATE);
        mDrawingThread.setRunning(true);
        mDrawingThread.start();
        onConfigurationChanged(getResources().getConfiguration());
    }

    public Bitmap createBitmap() {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Sticker[] stickers = mStickers.toArray(new Sticker[mStickers.size()]);
        for (Sticker sticker : stickers) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(sticker.getBitmap(), new Matrix(), mPaint);
        } return bitmap;
    }

    public void drawSurface(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bitmap = createBitmap();
        mMatrix.setScale(1.0f / mScaleFactor, 1.0f / mScaleFactor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);
    }

    private void setScaleFactor() {
         mScaleFactor = ((float) mBitmap.getWidth()) / getWidth();
    }

    public void addSticker(int drawableId) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        Sticker sticker = new Sticker(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId, options),
                new PointF(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight()),
                mScaleFactor);
        mActiveSticker = sticker;
        mStickers.add(sticker);
    }
}
```

This is my custom `Thread`:

```
public class DrawingThread extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean mRunning = false;

    private long mRefreshRate;
    private DrawingSurface mSurface;

    public DrawingThread (DrawingSurface surface, long time) {
        super();
        mSurface = surface;
        mRefreshRate = time;
    }

    public void setRunning (boolean run) {
        mRunning = run;
        Log.d("DrawingThread", "Running: " + mRunning);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRunning) {
            try {
                sleep(mRefreshRate);
                onSurfaceUpdate();
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(Configuration config, Point fit, float ratio) {
        float width, height;
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            width = fit.y * ratio;
            height = fit.y;
        } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            width = fit.x;
            height = fit.x / ratio;
        } else {
            width = fit.x;
            height = fit.x / ratio;
        } mSurface.getHolder().setFixedSize((int) width, (int) height);
    }

    private void onSurfaceUpdate() {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = mSurface.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (mSurface.getHolder()) {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mSurface.drawSurface(canvas);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                mSurface.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the sticker class used to hold each separate `Canvas` and `Bitmap`:

```
public class Sticker {
    private static final float START_SCALE = 0.5f;
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.3f;
    private static final float MAX_SCALE = 7f;

    private float mScale = 1f;
    private float mScaleFactor;

    private Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();
    private Bitmap mSticker;
    private Bitmap mSurface;

    private PointF mCenter = new PointF();

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();

    public Sticker(Bitmap sticker, PointF size, float scaleFactor) {
        mSticker = sticker;

        mSurface = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) size.x, (int) size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mSurface);
        mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        setScaleFactor(scaleFactor);
        postSticker();
    }

    private void postSticker() {
        mMatrix.postScale(START_SCALE, START_SCALE);
        setCenter();
        setTranslate(mCenter.x, mCenter.y);
    }

    public boolean collider(PointF point) {
        int x = (int) (point.x * mScaleFactor);
        int y = (int) (point.y * mScaleFactor);
        int color = mSurface.getPixel(x, y);

        if(color != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mSurface;
    }

    public void flipSticker() {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
        mSticker = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSticker, 0, 0,
                mSticker.getWidth(), mSticker.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }

    public void setScaleFactor(float scaleFactor) {
        mScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    }

    public void setTranslate(float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        mMatrix.postTranslate(deltaX * mScaleFactor, deltaY * mScaleFactor);
        draw();
    }

    public void setScale(float deltaScale, PointF midpoint) {
        mScale *= deltaScale;
        if(MIN_SCALE < mScale && mScale < MAX_SCALE) {
            mMatrix.postScale(deltaScale, deltaScale,
                    midpoint.x * mScaleFactor, midpoint.y * mScaleFactor);
        } draw();
    }

    public void setRotate(float deltaRotate, PointF midpoint) {
        mMatrix.postRotate(deltaRotate, midpoint.x * mScaleFactor, midpoint.y * mScaleFactor);
        draw();
    }

    private void setCenter() {
        float width = (mSurface.getWidth() / 2) - ((mSticker.getWidth() / 2) * START_SCALE);
        float height = (mSurface.getHeight() / 2) - ((mSticker.getHeight() / 2) * START_SCALE);
         mCenter.set(width, height);
    }

    private void draw() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mSticker, mMatrix, mPaint);
    }
}
```

I have found various discussions on the same topic on StackOverflow, as well as other sites. All of them conclude that the flickering is due to how the `SurfaceView` handles buffering, using two surfaces to swap between. The solution consists of using a separate bitmap to draw all of the images to first, then drawing that bitmap to the `SurfaceView`. As you can see, I have done this in my `createBitmap` method, yet the flickering persists.

Comment: In your `drawSurface()`, if you start by calling `canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 0, 0)`, do you see red? When do you call `onSurfaceChanged()`? Why are you synchronizing on the SurfaceHolder? What does the flickering look like -- is it jumping backward, is it alternating between rendering and black? Recording with `screenrecord` and walking through it frame-by-frame can sometimes be illuminating.

Comment: @fadden No, don't see any red. `onSurfaceChanged()` is called during `onConfigurationChanged()` in `DrawingSurface`, just to resize the `SurfaceView`. To be honest, I have no clue why I am synchronizing on the `SurfaceHolder`, must've seen it in some of the tutorials I've used. Everything seems to run the same without it. As for the flickering, the background is always rendered fine, but the bitmaps I draw on top do not appear to be finished drawing between each frame. Most of the time they are cut in half, with top half showing, sometimes its the bottom half, and sometimes its cut into lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the flickering was due to the `Canvas` drawing to the bitmap not being finished before it gets used in `createBitmap()`. I altered the method `getBitmap()` to return `mSticker` instead of the much larger `mSurface` (which is used to detect where the user is touching), so that the bitmap being drawn was not so large. And I added the method `getMatrix()` to return the `mMatrix` from each `Sticker`, and used that for the `canvas.drawBitmap()` method in `createBitmap()`. This stopped the flickering, even though the png files I use for my stickers are fairly large (most are 1024 x 1024).

Comment: If you're drawing into a bitmap on one thread, and rendering from that bitmap on another thread, you will need to synchronize the threads to remove race conditions.